# 3D Scatterplot: Multi Value Plot, coloring by column

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot, scatter3d, scatterplot3d

I want to perform a 3d scatterplot with a dataframe, which has the following format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
           "A_x1": [1, 2, 2, 2],
           "A_x2": [9, 2, 2, 3],
           "A_x3": [1, 3, 2, 9],
           "B_x1": [1, 8, 2, 3],
           "B_x2": [3, 8, 9, 3],
           "B_x3": [2, 4, 5, 5],
           "C_x1": [2, 6, 5, 2],
           "C_x2": [4, 8, 1, 3],
           "C_x3": [6, 9, 5, 7]})
```

| Date | A_x1 | A_x2 | A_x3 | B_x1 | B_x2 | B_x3 | C_x1 | C_x2 | C_x3 | D_x1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 9 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 6 | ... |
| 2021-01-02 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 8 | 8 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 9 | ... |
| 2021-01-03 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 9 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 5 | ... |
| 2021-01-04 | 2 | 3 | 9 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 7 | ... |

As you could guess: The 3 axis of the 3d Scatterplot shall be x1, x2 and x3. So I have 3 variables for 3 axis, but multiple values for each row.
I want to plot the values of A_x1/2/3, B_x1/2/3 etc. to the respective point and color them (f. ex. A = red, B = green, C = blue etc.).

I tried to use matplotlib and plotly but I'm open to any other libraries.
To get an dataframe or array for all x_1 values I use the following code.

```
df_x_1 = df.filter(like='1') #df x_1
x_1 = df_x_1.to_numpy() #arr_x_1
```

This is the simpliest scatterplot in plotly, works fine:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, 
                    x='A_x1', 
                    y='A_x2', 
                    z='A_x3',
                    #color='species'
                    )
fig.show()
```

Part of the problem, which has been solved by @Ynjxsjmh spoilered:

> But this obv. plots the x1, x2, x3 values for A (=3 columns), I want all >!columns to be included.
> I want to do something like this but I get different errors. Tried with >!dataframe and arrays.
> code

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(x=df.filter(like='1').values.ravel('F'),
                    y=df.filter(like='2').values.ravel('F'),
                    z=df.filter(like='3').values.ravel('F'),
                    color = ( df.filter(like='3').values.ravel('F')*df.filter(like='2').values.ravel('F')*df.filter(like='1').values.ravel('F') )**(1/3)

                    )
fig.show()
```

This code works now. The datapoints (f. ex. A_x1,x2,x3 are presentet at the corrects spots).
What toping is still unclear: Coloring.

Now I'm coloring the datapoints according to their geometrical size by doing color=(x_1*x_2*x_3)^(1/3)

What i want:
Color the Datapoints according to the name of column or the first row of dataframe or whatever (I will have to add this row, but that shall not be a problem).

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`x`, `y` and `z` of [plotly.express.scatter_3d()](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter_3d) should be [*str*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) *or* [*int*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) *or* *Series* *or* *array-like*. `df.filter(like='1')` returns a dataframe.

You can use [numpy.ravel()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to flatten the values in column direction.

```py
fig = px.scatter_3d(x=df.filter(like='1').values.ravel('F'),
                    y=df.filter(like='2').values.ravel('F'),
                    z=df.filter(like='3').values.ravel('F'),
                    )
```

Comment: Works fine, thank you.
Any ideas on how to tackle that color problem? I will edit my original post to adress it properly again.